# Animate Wordpress site navigation menu

Tags: css, wordpress, animation, navigation

I have this site: http://bit.ly/1p1Dr9W

This navigation looks kind of blank. I'd love to add css animation to it. I tried using opacity, but it does not work as intended. What am I doing wrong?

I added hover animation over each navigation elements and it works fine, but I'd like to add animation to whole navigation menu, so the whole list of sub menu elements would open with some animation (for example slow opacity to 1).

This is what i got:

```
#menu-menyy li ul {
background-color: transparent; }

#menu-menyy li ul:hover {
background-color: #00a3fc !important; 
-o-transition:.8s;
-ms-transition:.8s;
-moz-transition:.8s;
-webkit-transition:.8s;
transition:.8s;}
```

But whole navigation menu still just pops open, and as i move my mouse over the actual menu, i see the transition in the background. Can this be done in CSS afterall or it is made with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change css to

```
#menu-menyy li ul {
opacity: 0; }

#menu-menyy li:hover ul {
background-color: #00a3fc !important;
opacity: 1.0;
  -o-transition: opacity .8s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .8s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .8s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .8s;
  transition: opacity .8s;
}
```

Comment: Edited: changed it so opacity is affected on hover

Comment: THANKS! Duh, so easy solution.. :)

Comment: I used the same solution to add this animation to second level menu elements, but now the freaking arrow icon is displayed under the animation on second elements.. is there any way to only display that arrow in 1st level navigation menu? I mean that: .sf-menu li ul {
width: 190px;
background: url('images/header_submenu_arrow.png') 20px 30px no-repeat;
padding-top: 38px;
}

Comment: Use another selector to select sub sub ul elements, and set their background to none: `ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
background: none;}`